# Any TextMate trick/bundle to lookup Rails documentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate, textmatebundles

I know this is common in 'full featured' IDE's and not text editors but TextMate walks a unique line with its many bundles... I'm wondering if there is an easy way to, say, click on a Ruby or Rails class or method and have TextMate (or shell) take me to the definition or some documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one built into the rails bundle (`^h`) which uses api dock.

Another pretty nice way of doing it is using the [rails os x dictionary](http://breakthebit.org/post/989012581/awesome-rails-api-documentation-inside-textmate), but it has a few downsides and I'm not sure what version of rails it's using (I'm pretty sure it's not rails 3, but I haven't checked).

Answer (score 0):

**Ctrl-H** is an excellent option to learn about Ruby or Rails API.
But this doesn't work for any other methods or class that may be defined or included in your project. For those I've written a TextMate Bundle command (you can easily assign it to **Ctrl+]** for example) that lookup for the definition of the class or method under the caret and displays it in a tooltip, along with the file name and the line where it was find.

Check it out: **[Add a shortcut to TextMate to lookup a class or method definition in a tooltip](http://claudiofloreani.blogspot.com/2011/10/add-shortcut-to-textmate-to-lookup.html)**
Hope you'll find it useful ;)